# Parsing XML using TSQL

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I'm trying to parse out the following XML with TSQL:

```
<Response xmlns="http://data.fcc.gov/api" status="OK" executionTime="9">
    <Block FIPS="181770103002004" />
    <County FIPS="18177" name="Wayne" />
    <State FIPS="18" code="IN" name="Indiana" />
</Response>
```

Using the following script:

```
SELECT x.i.value('@name', 'varchar(200)') AS county
FROM @xml.nodes('Response/County') AS x(i)
```

But I get no results, any help as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XML namespace is messing things up.  Either remove the `xmlns="http://data.fcc.gov/api"` from the `Response` element, or prefix your query with `WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( DEFAULT 'http://data.fcc.gov/api')`

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( DEFAULT 'http://data.fcc.gov/api')
SELECT x.i.value('@name', 'varchar(200)') AS county
FROM @xml.nodes('Response/County') AS x(i)
```

Or you can use wildcard namespaces in the query:

```
SELECT x.i.value('@name', 'varchar(200)') AS county
FROM @xml.nodes('*:Response/*:County') AS x(i)
```

Comment: Right on the nose.  Both of those suggestions worked. I ended up removing the xmlns element and my script worked.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using OPENXML like this:

```
DECLARE @idoc INT
DECLARE @xml AS XML  = 

'<Response xmlns="http://data.fcc.gov/api" status="OK" executionTime="9">
    <Block FIPS="181770103002004" />
    <County FIPS="18177" name="Wayne" />
    <State FIPS="18" code="IN" name="Indiana" />
</Response>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xml, N'<root xmlns:n="http://data.fcc.gov/api" />'

SELECT
    Name AS County
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/n:Response/n:County', 1)
WITH
    (
        Name VARCHAR(255) '@name'
    )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
GO
```